# how to return to the original backgroundtint colour for edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-xml

Hi I have an edit text and I want to change the backgroundtint to the original color.

this way I am changing to the red colour but want to return to the original colour, how can I do that please

```
  etCostLimit.backgroundTintList = ColorStateList.valueOf(resources.getColor(
                                            R.color.newRed,
                                            null))
```

Thanks in advance
R

Comment: Set it to null.

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything, I finally found the answer on a C# forum. Converted that to Kotlin and combining other parts, here's the result (verified on API 21 and 33):

Consider editText as the variable name.

Backup:

```
val defaultTintList =
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && editText is AppCompatEditText) {
        null //reading current value also returns null
    } else {
        //restoring editText.backgroundTintList (which is null) doesn't work correctly
        val typedValue = TypedValue()
        context.theme.resolveAttribute(R.attr.colorAccent, typedValue, true)
        ColorStateList.valueOf(ContextCompat.getColor(context, typedValue.resourceId))
    }
```

Restore:

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP && editText is AppCompatEditText)
    (editText as AppCompatEditText).supportBackgroundTintList = defaultTintList
else
    editText.backgroundTintList = defaultTintList
```